# Delayed_job background process not sending mails while executing mail related code with delay option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, delay, delayed-job, background-process

While executing the mail related code asynchronously by using delay method of delayed_job, its executing properly but we didn't get mail.
we are getting the following o/p in jobs:work rake task console

```
[Worker(host:ip-0AASDF pid:3512)] Starting job worker
[Worker(host:ip-0AASDF pid:3512)] UserMailer.deliver_author_notification completed after 0.4850
[Worker(host:ip-0AASDF pid:3512)] 1 jobs processed at 1.3072 j/s, 0 failed ...
```

I have the following code

```
UserMailer.delay.deliver_author_notification(self,nfication)
```

I am using rails 2.3.5 and delayed_job 2.0.8 version.

Please help me on this.
Thanks in advanced....

Comment: So, have you checked your mailer settings? Please post them here.

Comment: We are getting mail while using mail related code normal way like UserMailer.deliver_author_notification(self,nfication)

Comment: So try to do it like this UserMailer.delay.author_notification(self,nfication)

Comment: In this scenario we are getting error as author_notification is not available in UserMailer.

Comment: Oops Sorry!... then it should work like this UserMailer.author_notification(self,nfication).delay

Comment: with the above change also we are getting undefined method author_notification for UserMailer:class error

Comment: Can you just post your code here

Comment: UserMailer.deliver_author_notification(self,nfication)

Comment: Run it like this UserMailer.author_notification(self,nfication).delay. Remove "deliver" and append ".delay"

Comment: I have also tried as per above, but this time also we are getting undefined method author_notification for UserMailer:class error

Comment: Post your user_mailer here

Answer (score 0):

user_mailer.rb contains the following code:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
   def author_notification(user,nfication)
     @recipients = user.creator.email
     @site_url = get_site_url(user.creator.organization)
     @from = "admin@#{@site_url}"
     @body[:body_template] = eval('"'+nfication.body+'"')
     @subject = eval('"'+nfication.subject+'"')
     content_type "text/html"
   end
end
```